# C Realloc causing segmentation fault

Tags: c, memory-management, realloc

I am using following function to allocate memory:

```
int qmem_alloc(unsigned int num_bytes, void ** rslt){

void** temp;
if(rslt == NULL)
    return -1;
temp = (void **)malloc(num_bytes);
if(temp == NULL)
    return -2;
else
    rslt = temp;
    return 0;
}
```

And following function to reallocate memory:

```
int  qmem_allocz(unsigned num_bytes, void ** rslt){
void** temp;
void *test = (void *)malloc(10);
if(rslt == NULL)
    return -1;
temp = (void **)realloc(rslt, num_bytes);
printf("here");
if(temp == NULL)
    return -2;
else
    // free(rslt)

    return 0;
  }
```

Here is my main function:

```
struct qbuf { int idx; char data[256]; };
void main(){
struct qbuf * p = NULL;
printf("%d\n",qmem_alloc(sizeof(struct qbuf), (void **)&p));
printf("%d\n",qmem_allocz(100*sizeof(struct qbuf), (void **)&p));
}
```

The program can get memory allocated but it crashes when reallocation is done. Here is the error:

> malloc.c:2868: mremap_chunk: Assertion `((size + offset) & (GLRO
>   (dl_pagesize) - 1)) == 0' failed.

Why is this happening? How can i fix it?

Comment: Fix your code with `*rlst = temp;` before return in the alloc function. `rlst = temp;` assigns the pointer value to temp, you need to assign the value to which the pointer points to temp.

Comment: Curiosus, who or what text suggested casting, like `(void **)`, the result of `malloc()`.?

Comment: What is the reason for `void *test = (void *)malloc(10);`?  It allocates memory and then code forgets about it.

Answer (score 2):

Your allocation in `qmem_alloc` is wrong.

```
temp = (void **)malloc(num_bytes); //You are wrongly typecasting, don't typecast the malloc return.
rslt = temp; // This makes rslt points to object where temp is pointing
```

You simply need to do as below.

```
int qmem_alloc(unsigned int num_bytes, void ** rslt){
  if(rslt == NULL)
    return -1;

   *rslt = malloc(num_bytes);
   if(*rslt == NULL && num_bytes > 0)
      return -2;
   else
      return 0;
}
```

And your reallocation is wrong

`temp = (void **)realloc(rslt, num_bytes); //You need to pass the object where rslt is pointing.`

Sample code for reallocation:

```
int  qmem_allocz(unsigned num_bytes, void ** rslt){
   void* temp; // No pointer to pointer is needed

   void *test = (void *)malloc(10);
   if (test == NULL) return -3;

   if(rslt == NULL)
      return -1;

   temp = realloc(*rslt, num_bytes); //use *rslt to pass the address of object where rslt is pointing.

   if(temp == NULL && num_bytes > 0){
      return -2;
    }
    else{
     *rslt = temp;
      return 0;
    }
}
```